# Add Image to email message not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add an image to an email in ASP.NET MVC, I got this following code which does send the email, but the image does not appear initially, I have to open the email, close it and open it again, What Am I doing wrong?

```
var message += "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=abc%20123%20456&choe=UTF-8' />";

            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.x.xx"))
            {
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("john@example.com");
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@example.com");
                MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
                email.Subject = "Subject";
                email.Body = message;
                email.IsBodyHtml = true;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(email);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex);
                }
            }
```

Comment: On which mail client does this occur?

Comment: Depends among others on the mail client being used, the domain where the image is hosted and the attributes on the image element. Try searching.

Comment: This is happening in apple mail

Comment: @user979331 Likely a security setting in your mail client. Images not directly embedded in the email message itself are generally blocked until a user explicitly allows them.

Comment: So I should embed this instead? How would I do that?

Comment: @user979331 Something [like this](https://gist.github.com/Brad-Christie/282016282b0b743c6a4a077728aa1e81).